# zend routes ini - giving priority one rule to another or define order

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes

I have following two rules in my routes.ini file

```
routes.frontcms.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontcms.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontcms.defaults.module = frontManagement
routes.frontcms.defaults.controller = Front
routes.frontcms.defaults.action = cmspages
routes.frontcms.map.locale = 1
routes.frontcms.map.page = 2
routes.frontcms.map.subpage = 3
routes.frontcms.map.num = 4


routes.frontnoncms.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontnoncms.route = "/?([a-z]{2}+)?/?(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.module = frontManagement
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.controller = Front
routes.frontnoncms.map.action = 2
routes.frontnoncms.map.locale = 1
routes.frontnoncms.map.page = 2
```

when I execute this url http://zf-cms.local/en/contactus
I get following results. which is expected. it executed the second rule

```
Array ( [locale] => en [action] => contactus [module] => frontManagement [controller] => Front )
```

when I execute this url http://zf-cms.local/en/privacy_policy
following are the results

```
Array ( [locale] => en [action] => [3] => privacy_policy [module] => frontManagement [controller] => Front )
```

It should execute the first rule. but because of conflict it won't able to decide which one to execute. 
Is there any possiblity we can define order that check second rule first and if it is not mactched then check second. some kind of priority or order?

Any one face similiar problem?

Comment: i used the chains but that also did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routes are checked in reverse order so it's already working the way you want it to. Your problem is that http://zf-cms.local/en/privacy_policy does match the regular expression in your second route, so the router doesn't need to check anything else.

For reference, here's your pattern:

```
"/?([a-z]{2}+)?/?(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
```

so if we break that down into bits, here's how the path `/en/privacy_policy` is matched:

```
([a-z]{2}+)/? -> matches en/
(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)?/? -> optional, so is skipped
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/? -> matches privacy_policy
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? -> optional, so is skipped
```

depending on how your URLs are structured the simplest solution might be to just make the second part non-optional by removing the ? after it:

```
"/?([a-z]{2}+)?/?(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
```

Comment: very well explained. Thanks Tim. How silly I am. so simple. :) 1up and acepted. thanks for your time to explain it well.